# How to integrate a rest service provider in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 but I would really like to understand better how it works.
As seen [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Architecture), in SWO2 wiki, the architecture uses a Service Provider which is typically the app I am trying to secure.

So I deployed an instance of WSO2 IS on a server and tried to configure a Service provider. But the thing is I really don't know how it all works. I found the WSO2 page about Adding a Service Provider but I really don't understand how my REST service can be linked with it.

So my question is quite simple : is my REST API a Service Provider ? Can it be seen as such ?

I also have another questions that is linked. Can I, with WSO2 IS redirect the user to a connexion page when they try to access an address ? (Say http...../rest/myService) Or has it to be done inside the REST API ?

I have been looking for an answer for quite a long time now so even a redirection towards a tutorial would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the WSO2 IS docs we can find an answer for your first question:

> ***Working with the Service Provider***: A Service Provider (SP) is an entity that provides Web services.

So the SP is the Web Service where you exposed your API.

For the second question, the answer is **yes**. It is possible and WSO2 suite has many ways to do it which depends for what and how you want do it.

*For example*:

You can expose your API in WSO2 ESB with [REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Creating+APIs). Then you can [Secure the API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Securing+APIs) using BasicAuth. In the doc sample it demands an Authorization hearder to your request, so the redirect could happen on BasicAuthHandler implementation or using Mediation Sequences.

If you are lost I recommend you first to decide what you want to accomplish and what architecture is the best to do it. With this in mind is pretty easy to follow the WSO2 documentation samples and achieve your goals.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you ! It really helped me !
It's true that it felt a little unclear. But thank you.